# How Do I Open Heroku PostgresQL Database from my Terminal (I need the command)

Tags: postgresql, heroku, terminal

What is the command to open Heroku PostgresQL database from my Terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh wow it's simple, but it's hard to find docs on:

```
heroku pg:psql
```